# How to handle style classes in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, material-design

I need add class dynamically and remove when it need it 
I'm using texfield component from google material. When text input does not pass validation, error comes up , input borders should be red and a warning message below it. When everything is ok,  green check icon. Picture below how it supposed to be. 
[image]
All text goes thru regex validation  and stores in error array (data->textfields-> errors) Thats how I track it if there is an error.
[image]

Here I'm dynamically adding styles when there is an error.The problem is when i'm clearing input (empty) 'tf-error' class still there with red borders, but I need to remove it, like it was before adding class 'tf-error'.    What should I do?

```
gmcTextfield(
  v-for='(item, idx) in textfields'
  :key='idx'

  :inputId='"textfield-"+idx'
  label='item.label'
  :className=`['fs', [textfields[idx].errors ? 'tf-error' : '']]`


  :reference='item'
  refProp='value'

  :numOfErrorMsgs='item.numOfErrorMsgs'


)
```

Comment: It looks like the `errors` property is an array. You should probably check its length instead of just its existence

Comment: yes , errors  is an array. How do you suggest to check length?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Answer (score 0):

I use in Vue the class binding to apply dynamic classes. You can see the [doc](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html) here.

You define a binding for class and use an object as value, whre the key is the classes and the value is a boolean expression.

As example

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in menuItems"
      v-on:click="selected = item"
      v-bind:class="{ selected: selected == item}">
     {{item}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: here :className=`['fs', [textfields[idx].errors ? 'tf-error' : '']]` i'm binding classes